# Como mudar a cor do texto de uma coluna de uma JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Tenho um formulário para pagamento de parcelas, e este formulário possui uma tabela onde mostro tanto as parcelas pagas quanto as que ainda deveriam ser pagas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para popular esta `JTable`, faço uma consulta no banco de dados e trago as informações necessárias.

```
public void preencherParcelas(String SQL) {
    ArrayList dados = new ArrayList();
    String[] colunas = new String[]{"Data Pagamento", "Valor Parcela", "Status Pagamento"};
    conecta.conexao();
    conecta.executaSQL(SQL);
    String status;
    try {
        conecta.rs.first();
        dataVenda = conecta.rs.getString("data_venda");
        idParcelamento = conecta.rs.getInt("id_parcelamento");
        do {

            if (conecta.rs.getInt("status_pagamento") == 0) {
                status = "PAGAMENTO PENDENTE";
            } else {
                status = "PAGAMENTO EFETUADO";
            }

            dados.add(new Object[]{conecta.rs.getString("data_pagamento"), "R$ " + conecta.rs.getString("valor_parcelas"), status});

        } while (conecta.rs.next());
} catch (SQLException ex) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "ERRO AO LOCALIZAR PARCELAS" + ex);

    }

ModeloTabela modelo = new ModeloTabela(dados, colunas);

    jTableInformaVencimentos.setModel(modelo);
    jTableInformaVencimentos.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(150);
    jTableInformaVencimentos.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);

    jTableInformaVencimentos.setModel(modelo);
    jTableInformaVencimentos.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(150);
    jTableInformaVencimentos.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);

    jTableInformaVencimentos.setModel(modelo);
    jTableInformaVencimentos.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(150);
    jTableInformaVencimentos.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);

    jTableInformaVencimentos.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    jTableInformaVencimentos.setAutoResizeMode(jTableInformaVencimentos.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    jTableInformaVencimentos.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    conecta.desconecta();
```

Modelo usado na Tabela

```
    public class ModeloTabela extends AbstractTableModel{

    private ArrayList linhas = null;
    private String[] colunas = null;

    public ModeloTabela(ArrayList lin, String[] col){
        setLinhas(lin);
        setColunas(col);

    }
    public ArrayList getLinhas(){
        return linhas;
    }

    public void setLinhas(ArrayList dados){
        linhas = dados;
    }

    public String[] getColunas(){
        return colunas;
    }

    public void setColunas (String[] nomes){
        colunas = nomes;
    }

    public int getColumnCount(){
        //retorna a quantidade de colunas(conta a quantidade e retorna)
        return colunas.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount(){
        //retorna o tamanho do array(quantos letras tem)
        return linhas.size();
    }

    public String getColumnName(int numCol){
        return colunas[numCol];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int numLin, int numCol){
        Object[] linha = (Object[])getLinhas().get(numLin);
        return linha[numCol];
    }

}
```

Gostaria de quando for identificado um "*PAGAMENTO EFETUADO*" essa *String* ficasse na cor vermelha de preferencia. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: String? Você quer dizer celular da tabela ne?

Comment: Tanto faz o que for mais fácil... Se for só a String mesmo e inserir ela já com a cor nova.

Comment: Não é a mesma coisa colorir string e colorir célula. Você precisa definir o que você quer de fato para que a reposta seja condizente ao problema.

Comment: Quero colorir a String e inserir ela no jTable.

Comment: Somente o texto.

Comment: Somente da coluna pagamento ou o texto da linha inteira?

Comment: Só a palavra pagamento.

Comment: Adicione como você está preenchendo a jtable. Se tiver usando algum model ou renderer, adicione eles na pergunta também.

Comment: Está acima na pergunta, eu faço um select no banco e adiciono na tabela.

Comment: Não tem nenhum código que mostre como a jtable está sendo populada. Adicione na pergunta como vc esta populando a jtable.

Comment: Adicione o método getcolumnclass e getvalueat da sua classe modelotabela também.

Comment: O modelo que estou usando é esse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa alterar a forma como o `JTable` renderiza a célula na tela, e para isso, use a classe [`DefaultTableCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html), ou crie seu próprio renderer. A forma mais simples é usar a classe padrão citada:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column); 

        String str = (String) value;
        if ("PAGAMENTO EFETUADO".equals(str)) {
            c.setForeground(Color.RED);
        } else {
            c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
        return c;
    }
};
```

E depois, aplique o renderer a coluna desejada, no seu caso, a coluna 2:

```
jTableInformaVencimentos.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(renderer);
```

Lembrando que este renderer, se for aplicado como default da `JTable`, irá efetuar a alteração de cor para todas as colunas, por isso apliquei apenas a coluna informada.

Se quiser aprender mais sobre renderers, você pode acessar o [**tutorial oficial da oracle**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

Comment: Cara Perfeito... Funcionou exatamente como eu precisava. Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: @Valdecir Disponha :)