# Exibir data corretamente em um JTable

Tags: java, sql, swing, datetime

Não estou conseguindo exibir a data do banco sql tipo `Date` no JTable, a data aparece dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu uso o seguinte método pra chamar os dados da tabela:

```
public ArrayList<Alunos> read(){
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    ArrayList <Alunos> aluno = new ArrayList();

    try {
        stmt = connection.prepareStatement("select * from alunos");
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();//guarda os resultados do select no rs

        while(rs.next()){ //enquanto o select gerar valor, o while será executado
            Alunos alu = new Alunos();

            //Date data =  (Date) alu.getDataNascimento().getTime();
            alu.setId(rs.getInt("id"));//nome da coluna onde será mostrado 
            alu.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
            alu.setCpf(rs.getString("cpf"));
            alu.setRg(rs.getString("rg"));
            alu.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));
            alu.setEstado(rs.getString("estado"));
            alu.setDataNascimento(toCalendar(rs.getDate("nasc")));
            aluno.add(alu);

        }
        stmt.close();
        rs.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AlunoDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return aluno;
}

public static Calendar toCalendar(Date date){ 
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTime(date);
    return cal;
}
```

E aqui é onde chamo o método no `JPanel`:

```
public void readJTable(){//lê os dados para tabela
   DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) jTAlunos.getModel();

   AlunoDao aluDao = new AlunoDao();

   for(Alunos a: aluDao.read()){///adiciona linha na tabela
       modelo.addRow(new Object[]{
           a.getId(),
           a.getNome(),
           a.getCpf(),
           a.getRg(),
           a.getEndereco(),
           a.getEstado(),
           a.getDataNascimento().toString()
       });
   }
}
```

Essa é a classe onde guardo os dados:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Alunos {
private int id;
private String nome;
private String cpf;
private String rg;
private String endereco;
private String estado;
private Calendar dataNascimento;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}

public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}

public String getRg() {
    return rg;
}

public void setRg(String rg) {
    this.rg = rg;
}

public String getEndereco() {
    return endereco;
}

public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
    this.endereco = endereco;
}

public String getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(String estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}

public Calendar getDataNascimento() {
    return dataNascimento;
}

public void setDataNascimento(Calendar dataNascimento) {
    this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
}
```

}

Comment: Carlos, forneça um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel testar o codigo e propor uma solucao.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solução ideal seria utilizar classe de data na classe `Alunos`, pois não faz sentido usar `Calendar` pra armazenar uma "data de nascimento". Não sei se tem um bom motivo para isso, mas recomendo rever sua modelagem.

Usando `SimpleDateFormat` você não irá conseguir formatar um tipo `Calendar`, como foi sugerido na outra resposta. Basta uma consulta rápida na documentação do método [`SimpleDateFormat#format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#format-java.util.Date-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.text.FieldPosition-) para ver que ele espera um tipo `Date`.

Mesmo alterando o tipo para `Date`, para evitar gambiarras na exibição da `JTable`, você deveria [criar um renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)(exemplos [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237003/28595) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137437/28595)) para a coluna, mas como nem [escreveu um TableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), torna ainda mais difícil aplica-lo a tabela ou sugerir um renderer.

Recomendo que dê uma [lida a respeito de como criar um TableModel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121513/28595), pois ele pode facilitar expandir funcionalidades a sua tabela sem ter que ficar escrevendo um monde de código desnecessário como este laço que está usando para preenche-la. Recomendo também que leia a respeito das [novas classes de datas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177130/28595) do java, tendo em vista que tanto `Calendar` quanto a própria classe `Date` tem alguns problemas que foram corrigidos com a adição das novas classes junto ao java 8.

Supondo que, depois de tudo que foi dito acima, você ainda tenha um bom motivo para manter a implementação da forma que está, a solução talvez mais simples(mas nao quer dizer que seja boa) seja obter o tipo Date de Calendar através do método [`getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime--) e aplicar o formatador em seguida, dentro do laço:

```
for (Alunos a : aluDao.read()) {/// adiciona linha na tabela
    modelo.addRow(new Object[] { 
            a.getId(), 
            a.getNome(), 
            a.getCpf(), 
            a.getRg(), 
            a.getEndereco(), 
            a.getEstado(),
            new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(a.getDataNascimento().getTime()) 
    });
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, sou iniciante em java, mas vou pesquisar tudo oque vc disse.

Answer (score -1):

Acho que você só precisa formatar a data, fazendo assim:

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");

 for(Alunos a: aluDao.read()){///adiciona linha na tabela
   modelo.addRow(new Object[]{
       a.getId(),
       a.getNome(),
       a.getCpf(),
       a.getRg(),
       a.getEndereco(),
       a.getEstado(),
       formatter.format(a.getDataNascimento())
   });
}
```

Não tenho certeza se funciona com o tipo Calendar.

Comment: Iago, voce ao menos testou? Esse código nem vai compilar.